# Ajax not showing success message

Tags: ajax

I have Ajax and it runs successfully, but it's not showing success message and it's not reloading page. In console, it's returning not only 'success' but also some HTML. What is the reason of this? This should cause problem.

My console has following:

```
success<html>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400,300,600,700&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>
.boldText,.boldText td{
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight: bold !important;
}
//and some other html
```

Ajax is:

```js
function sendQuoteMail() {
 var send_options = $('input[name=send_options]:checked').val(),
  offer_id = $("#SendQuoteMail").attr('data-offer-id'),
  send_free_message = $("#send_free_message").val(),
  atm = $("#alternative_transport_mode").val(),
  lang = $("#selectlangoffer").val(),
  options = [];

 if(typeof atm != 'undefined' && atm != null && atm.length > 0 && atm != '') {
  $('#quoteInfo .accordion-group').each(function () {
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   id = id.substr(6);

   options.push(id);
  });
 } else {
  $("#quoteInfo input.addToGenerateOffer:checkbox:checked").each(function () {
   options.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
  });
 }

 if(options.length === 0) {
  options = false;
 }

 console.log('Sent options: ' + options); //return;

 $.ajax({
  url: Base_URL + "/offers/preSendOffer",
  type: "POST",
  data:   {
     "offer_id": offer_id,
     "send_options":send_options,
                                        "send_free_message": send_free_message,
                                        "lang": lang,
          "atm": atm,
          "options": options,
          "quote_general_info_id": quoteData['quote_general_info_id']
    },
  success: function (data) {
   if(data === 'success') {
    MessageBoxOK(translate('Quote send successfully'));
    window.location.reload();
    
   }
  },
  error: function (data) {
   MessageBoxError(translate('You don\'t have access to MyUnimasters Portal!'));
  }
 });
}
```

Controller is:

```html
 public function action_preSendOffer() {
        $this->auto_render = false;
  $change_statuses = true;
        if($_POST) {
//            print '<pre>'; print_r($_POST);exit;
            $lang = isset($_POST['lang']) ? $_POST['lang']:$this->current_lang;
   $atm = (!empty($_POST['atm']) AND in_array($_POST['atm'], array('ROA', 'AIR', 'LCL', 'FCL')))?$_POST['atm']:false;
            //TODO: NOT property status !!!
            if($_POST['status'] != 'draft')
            {

            }
            //
            Model_Offers::saveOfferDate($_POST['offer_id']);
            //
            $body = $this->action_sendOffer($_POST['offer_id'], $_POST['send_options'], $lang);
//            $body .= "\r\n" . $_POST['send_free_message'];

   if($_POST['send_options'] != 'none')
   {
    $mailer = email::connect();
//    $mailer->registerPLugin(new Swift_Plugins_FilterPlugin('', $this->emailsBlacklist));
                $subject = __ ( 'Quote for inquire ID: ' ).$_POST['offer_id'];
    $body_temp = (!empty($_POST['send_free_message']))?$_POST['send_free_message'].'<hr />':'';

    $body = $body_temp.$body;

                $to = Model_Offers::getEmail($_POST['offer_id']);
                $cc_to = Model_Offers::getCcEmail($_POST['offer_id']);
                $from = Helper_Emails::$company_mail;
                if($_POST['send_options'] == 'PDF')
                {
                    //
                    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/pdfs/';
                    $attachment = Swift_Attachment::fromPath($path.'offer_'.$_POST['offer_id'].'.pdf');
     if($cc_to != '') {
      $message_swift =  Swift_Message::newInstance ( $subject, $body , "text/html" )
          ->setContentType("application/pdf")
          ->attach($attachment)
          ->setFrom ( $from )
          ->setTo ( $to )
          ->setCc ($cc_to);
     } else {
      $message_swift =  Swift_Message::newInstance ( $subject, $body , "text/html" )
          ->setContentType("application/pdf")
          ->attach($attachment)
          ->setFrom ( $from )
          ->setTo ( $to );

     }
                    //
                    try {

                        if($mailer->send($message_swift))
                        {
                           
//                            Model_QuoteOptions::changeStatusByOfferId($_POST['offer_id'], 'sent', false);
                            unlink($path.'offer_'.$_POST['offer_id'].'.pdf');
                            print 'success';
                        } else {
       $change_statuses = false;
                            print 'error';
      }
                    } catch (Exception $ex) {

                    }

                } else {  
                   
                    if($cc_to != '') {
                            $message_swift =  Swift_Message::newInstance ( $subject, $body , "text/html" )->setFrom ( $from )->setTo ( $to )->setCc($cc_to);
                    } else {
                            $message_swift =  Swift_Message::newInstance ( $subject, $body , "text/html" )->setFrom ( $from )->setTo ( $to );
                    }
                    try {
        if($mailer->send($message_swift))
                        {
                            print 'success';
                        } else {
       $change_statuses = false;
                            print 'error';
      }
                    } catch (Exception $ex) {

                    }
                }
   }
   if($change_statuses === true)
   {
    //Change status of offer and inquiry
    if($atm != false) {
     //Change status of sent options
     if(!empty($_POST['options']) AND is_array($_POST['options'])) {
      Model_QuoteOptions::changeStatusByOfferId($_POST['offer_id'], 'sent', false, $_POST['options'], $atm);
     }

//                 if(Model_QuoteOptions::checkIfAllSent($_POST['offer_id'], $atm)) {
      Model_AlternativeOffers::updateAlternativeOffer($_POST['offer_id'], $atm, array('status' => 'completed'));
//      Model_QuoteGeneralInfo::changeStatusQuote($_POST['offer_id'], 'sent', $_POST['quote_general_info_id']);
//     }
    } else {
     //Change status of sent options
     if(!empty($_POST['options']) AND is_array($_POST['options'])) {
      Model_QuoteOptions::changeStatusByOfferId($_POST['offer_id'], 'sent', false, $_POST['options']);
     }

      
    }
                print 'success'; 
   }
            else {
                print 'error';
            }
            

        } 
            
        
    }
    //
```

Comment: can you add the server side code which the AJAX is calling?

Comment: Also, clientside as well. We are not mindreaders. :)